# Position image + text together?

Tags: html, css

How would I go about placing my text at the center of an image, this is what it looks right now: http://gyazo.com/442aa9f927c1c1ee505435c2422f7322.png

and this is how I want it to be: http://gyazo.com/bc3bb2d0472a1c963d4ac00081065461.png

This is my current code:

```
<p><img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/941/web_design/32/page_text.png" /> Some random text</p>
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to insert the image inside a div and put the text on it like this:

```
<div class="img">
   <p>your text</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.img{
    background: url('http://findicons.com/files/icons/941/web_design/32/page_text.png') no-repeat;
    height:100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C6t5r/2/)

After you can mode your text where you want

If you don't want to use the image like a background and you want only to put text at the center of your element try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/941/web_design/32/page_text.png" />
    <span>your text</span>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

.container span{
    line-height:30px;
    float:left;
}

.container img{
    float:left;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/C6t5r/1/)

Comment: Hmm, that works but a part of the image is gone (at the bottom) and I would need need to create a new code in the css for each image that I am going to use, which is 20+.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5ser6/1/

```
 <div class="thingy">
     <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/941/web_design/32/page_text.png" alt="" />        
       <p>Text</p>
     <br style="clear:both;">
  </div>


   * {font-family:arial}
   .thingy img {float:left;}
   .thingy {height:32px;float:left;}
   .thingy p {float:left;margin:0 0 0 10px;padding:0;line-height:32px;}
```

If your framework has a clearfix, you don't need the clear:both, just put a clearfix on the outer div.

Comment: Are you stacking these? Where do they go. If you use this, it will need to be cleared on the main wrapper to stack and or you stick a wrapper around the wrapper.